# How to move systray icons to the top panel on Fedora 21?

Tags: fedora, gnome, gnome-shell, fedora-21

I used `gnome-shell-classic-systray` [package on Ubuntu 14.10](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/04/gnome-shell-classic-systray-message.html), and it worked great - but now that I've moved to Fedora 21, I can't find a way to move systray icons/applets (such as Skype, Dropbox, etc.) from the auto-hide bottom notifications panel to the top right - like this:

[image]

None of [GNOME extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org) help either.

Is there a way to do this on Gnome 3.14?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TopIcons extension does exactly what I need, and it's working on Fedora 21:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/495/topicons/